# Feedback when entering passwords, without revealing length

Tags: ssh, sudo, password

I often SSH into a machine and use `sudo` on it. When entering passwords, I'm always afraid that another window will steal the focus. However, I don't want to display asterisks (with [`pwfeedback`](https://superuser.com/questions/420815/feedback-when-typing-password-at-a-sudo-prompt), for example) because that would reveal the number of characters.

Is there a tool available that could give a visual feedback for every character entered, without revealing the number of characters typed? Something like a pipe that rotates on key presses? Basically, anything that moves on key presses would be fine.

In my particular case, this tool would need to work with both SSH and `sudo`. The target machine is running Ubuntu 15.10. I'm usually SSHing into it using putty from Windows 10.

Comment: @techraf I would normally prefer not showing _any_ information about my password. However, in this particular case, I'm more concerned about typing my password in the wrong window than someone looking over my shoulder. I was trying to to compromise: visual feedback that would be difficult to utilize to gather information.

Comment: `pwfeedback` solves this problem for you, what you have already noticed in your question. Why did it became a main point again?

Comment: Any password you use should be strong enough so that the knowledge of its length does not influence the security. Trying to hide this information by subverting native mechanisms that software offers is counterproductive and decreases security.

Comment: If you want to be safe from eavesdropping and shoulder-surfing, perhaps using passwords which change all the time would be better; something like HOTP or TOTP tokens using LinOTP... That way even if another window grabs the focus and your password ends up on IRC (or wherever), it doesn't matter quite so much.

Comment: By the way guys, I really appreciate the security lesson, but I'm really curious to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Giving visual feedback for every character entered would by definition reveal the number of characters typed, so by that metric, no, there is not a way to simultaneously do a thing and not do it.

Comment: Uh, okay. I thought having some sort of animation [like a spinner](http://fitnr.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/bash-spinner.gif) that would animate on key presses would be good enough. I guess you could count the number of rotations, but I wouldn't mind. Or maybe displaying a random amount of stars for each key. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Then I just need to count how many _times_ I see asterisks appear.

Comment: Sure. I'm not exactly Edward Snowden here, so I'll be fine as long as 1) something tells me I'm actually entering characters and 2) the resulting output has no correlation with the password length.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be used by `sudo` (probably yes, somehow) and it requires X display:

[image]

Certainly it works with `ssh` as demonstrated on the picture above. It is taken from Fedora, but I hope other distros have something similar.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I'm using putty on Windows 10, so X isn't easily available to me.

Comment: There are also X servers for windows ...